GEE ImageCollection can't use function such as reduceColumns() and size()
var CH = ee.ImageCollection('projects/meta-forest-monitoring-okw37/assets/CanopyHeight').mosaic().clip(table);
//var CH1 = ee.Image('projects/meta-forest-monitoring-okw37/assets/CanopyHeight').clip(table);

Map.addLayer(table);
Map.addLayer(CH);
var range = CH.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ['system:time_start'])
print('Date range: ', ee.Date(range.get('min')), ee.Date(range.get('max')))
var infomation = CH.size();
print(information);

this code run in GEE;
console back with error:
Line 7: CH.reduceColumns is not a function
How to fix it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you apply .mosaic() on Image collection, it returns image! Both reduceColumns and size don't work for image! You may clarify what do you want to achieve beyond fixing the error so one can answer the question in that direction

thanks, i just want to know the resolution of that image data, to download it with right resolution.
